# Paso como argumentos a un método

Tags: c#, unity3d

Buenas .

Como puedo declarar en una clase uno o mas metodos publicos con los argumentos que quiero?

Y como puedo pasar la variable data y imagenes a ese metodo?

este es el código que tengo

```
Código:
void Awake()
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(rutasapp))
        {
            foreach (string dataApp in Directory.GetDirectories(rutasapp))
            {
                GameObject button = Instantiate(buttonPrefab) as GameObject;
                button.transform.SetParent(layout);
                button.name = "Button" + layout.childCount;


                foreach (string data in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".exe") || s.EndsWith(".lnk")))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@data) == ".exe")
                    {
                        button.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => Process.Start(data));
                    }
                }


                foreach (string imagenes in Directory.GetFiles(@dataApp).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg")))
                {
                    if (Path.GetExtension(@imagenes) == ".png")
                    {
                        string imgPath = imagenes;

            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

@Roberto León Oramas mmmm okey hize esto en mi clase appbuton

```
public void prueba(Datos dato){
      this.dato = dato;    
}
```

pero la variable data y imagenes de la otra clase como los paso ?

Answer (score 0):

Lee el artículo [Métodos (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173114.aspx); particularmente el `main` no lo uso ya que es más común usarlo cuando crearas un ejecutable para consola.

Lo básico es:

```
public class MyClase {

   #region Propiedades

   public tipoDato NombreVariable; // Puede ser private, public....
   // y las demás propiedades que necesites

   #endregion // Propiedades

   #region Métodos

   // Sin parámetros
   public void MiMetodo() {
      // todo tu código que corresponda
   }


   // Con parámetros (método sobrecargado)
   public void MiMetodo(tipoDedatoParam1 param1 /* tantos parámetros como requieras  */) {
      // todo tu código que corresponda usando los parámetros
   }

   /* Los métodos pueden ser públicos, privados, protected... 
      como quieras y hasta donde sean accesdidos.
      Puedes sobrecargarlos para mayor flexibilidad en tu código
      pero cuidando queno exista más de uno que reciba el/los mismo(s) 
      tipo(s) de parámetro(s) en el mismo orden */

   // INICIO: ejemplo sobre carga no permitida pues es lo mismo
   // Sin parámetros
   public void MiMetodo2() {
      // todo tu código que corresponda
   }

   // Con parámetros (método sobrecargado)
   public void MiMetodo2(string param1="") {
      // todo tu código que corresponda usando los parámetros
   }
   /*
      Explicación sencilla: 
         No aceptara el "MiMetodo2" que recibe opcionalmente un string
         por que es lo mismo que el primero sin parámetros, tendrias que
         quitarle el '=""' que lo hace opcional si en ambos se realizan 
         procesos distinto, pero si al final de cuentas es lo mismo
         sería dejar el que recibe parámetroo el que se debe dejar 
   */

   // FIN: ejemplo sobre carga no permitida pues es lo mismo


   #endregion // Métodos

   #region Constructor

   public MyClase ()  {
     // inicialización de propiedades que existan y se requieran
   }

   #endregion // Constructor

}
```

**Ejemplo de uso**

```
// Tu código antes de usar la clase y hasta donde obtienes "data"

MyClase miclase= new MyClase(); // Si al constructor le pones parámetros debes colocarlos

miclase.MiMetodo(data); // Aqui usas "data"
// Tu código usando "miclase"

// Tu código despues de usar la clase
```